# the truth value of a Series is ambiguous: value error python

Tags: python, valueerror

I am trying to fill a column in my dataset using the following condition.

```
def shorthaul(df):
    for i in df:
        if df['Distance'] <= 250:
            df['margin'] = 65
```

When I try to run this the following error pops up:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I would appreciate any help to solve this issue.

Comment: Let's say `df['Distance'] <= 250` is `[True, False, True]`, what do you want to happen next?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `loc` instead:

```
df.loc[df['Distance'] <= 250, 'margin'] = 65
```